# Mask-composite for svg path subtract

Tags: css, svg

I am working with a svg material which contains two `paths`, one solid green **with gap inbetween** and one dashed red **with no gap inbetween**

**Red Dashed**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 100">    
  <path id ='lineNoGap' d="M0,80L50,20L100,50L150,30L200,40L250,90L400,20L450,70L500,60" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="2" />  
</svg>
```

**Green Solid**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 100">      
  <path id ='lineWithGap' d="M0,80L50,20L100,50L150,30L200,40L250,90M400,20L450,70L500,60" stroke="green" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Is there any way I can have the red line generated only for the `gap` that appeared in green line? My desired end goal is to achieve the following where **`red line appears only for the gap in green line`**.

[image]

I tried using `mask-composite` in the following way which did not work.

```css
#dashedRedNoGap {  
mask:url(#solidGreenWithGap);
-webkit-mask-composite: exclude;    
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 100">  
        <mask id="solidGreenWithGap">    
    <path d="M0,80L50,20L100,50L150,30L200,40L250,90L400,20L450,70L500,60" /> 
  </mask>
  <path id ='solidGreenWithGap' d="M0,80L50,20L100,50L150,30L200,40L250,90M400,20L450,70L500,60" stroke="green" fill="none" />
  <path id ='dashedRedNoGap' d="M0,80L50,20L100,50L150,30L200,40L250,90L400,20L450,70L500,60" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="2"/>  
 <!--<path id ='solidGreenWithGap' d="M0,80L50,20L100,50L150,30L200,40L250,90M400,20L450,70L500,60" stroke="green" fill="none" />-->   
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you don't use the same id twice. In this example the mask is made up of both paths there the fill path is white (transparent) and the broken path is black. That leaves just the gap visible. This mask is applied to the red dotted path.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 100">
  <mask id="mask1">
    <path d="M0,80L50,20L100,50L150,30L200,40L250,90L400,20L450,70L500,60" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="10"/> 
    <path d="M0,80L50,20L100,50L150,30L200,40L250,90M400,20L450,70L500,60" stroke-width="10" stroke="black" fill="none" />
  </mask>
  <path d="M0,80L50,20L100,50L150,30L200,40L250,90M400,20L450,70L500,60" stroke="green" fill="none" />
  <path d="M0,80L50,20L100,50L150,30L200,40L250,90L400,20L450,70L500,60" stroke="red" fill="none" mask="url(#mask1)" stroke-dasharray="2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. As I understand, the target (the element on which the mask is applied) will be on top of the source (the mask)  inside `<mask></mask>` and exactly opposite outside of `<mask></mask>`. I want to generate this programmatically, hence want to strengthen my understanding. `Make sure that you don't use the same id twice` can you please elaborate on this what you meant by this? Thanks again.

Comment: @smpa01 **Unique id:** In the code that you have in the question both the mask element and the path element have the id "solidGreenWithGap". In your CSS you refer to "solidGreenWithGap" -- but the browser cannot guess which element it should pick. **Mask:** The mask is a black/white (and gray scale) "image"/filter. It is only the part of the masked element that is "covered" by white and lighter gray mask that will show.